# Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability. Can't set package name

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-security, android-securityexception

I have that vulnerability according to google play console.
It's supposed that the solution is to add `.setPackage()` or `.setClassName()` to the intent but now the activity is not being recognized. How can I use this function?
The intent as it was with the vulnerability is this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent("independent.dev.ui.mainactivity");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The solution that I tried adding the package name:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent("independent.dev.ui.mainactivity");
        intent.setPackage("independent.dev.ui.Activities");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

my `AndroidManifest.xml` is this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="independent.dev.ui.Activities">
.
.
.
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Menu Principal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="independent.dev.ui.mainactivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

How can I set the package so I can navigate and delete this vulnerability?

Comment: Is `independent.dev.ui.Activities` your `applicationId`, as set in your Gradle build scripts?

Comment: No, mi aaplicationId is another one. But isn't it supposed that I have to set the package name?

Comment: Despite the name, `setPackage()` takes an `applicationId`.